# Load dart from Javascript?

Tags: dart

I have a normal HTML page which has loaded, how can I use Javascript to then load a dart script into the page and run the dart script?
The restriction I have is that I can only load Javascript at the beginning.

I then want to load a dart script and run it.

Comment: Are you taking about JS that is converted from Dart? After building a Dart web app you don't have any Dart left.

Comment: I have a HTML web page with Javascript and no dart include into the page. Then when the user clicks a button on my page I want to load a dart file and run it. Note that when the page first loads it does not load any dart code, only when the user clicks the button I want the dart code loaded.

Comment: This only works if the user has Dartium which is the only browser available that supports Dart. Currently the Dart development workflow is: develop in Dart, test in Dart, build to JavaScript, deploy. The end user's browser normally never sees some Dart code (until a browser like Chrome, Opera, Firefox, ... contain a Dart-VM which is not likely anytime soon).

Comment: Yes its ok to assume its Dartium, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `<script>` tags like below in your JavaScript and add it to your page dynamically.
I haven't tried it but I can't see why it shouldn't work.

```html
<script type="application/dart" src="yourscript.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mofify the dom dynamically using Javascript to add the elements then? Ok I will try and see thanks.